# Where to place Jmeter test and resource files on remote server?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have set up Jmeter on a server for remote testing but I, however, do not know how/where to configure jmeter-server to look for the `.jmx` file constituting my test plan.
I have replaced the file paths tothe resource file (i.e. the various CSV files I referenced locally) in the jmx file.
I'm working with Jmeter version 5.4.1 and also used [this guide](https://martijndevrieze.net/2014/12/02/jmeter-and-remote-servers-a-tutorial/) in setting up the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) is being transferred automatically from the master to the slave machine(s), you don't need to worry about it. The only thing to remember is that if you're using any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - you need to install them on the slave machine(s)
2. If you use relative paths to CSV files - on the slave they will be relative to the folder where you launch jmeter-server script from. Normally people launch JMeter from ["bin" folder](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/master/bin) so it makes sense to use file paths relative to JMeter's "bin" folder.

   Another approach is to use "central" location for the test data like [Redis Data Set](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/Using-Redis-Dataset-JMeter-Plugin) or [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/), this way you won't have to copy the test data to the slaves.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. Can I specify the paths to the csv files using the relative path notation? Like `../../some/relative/path` ?

Comment: Sure you can, moreover it's recommended way